# What is this part?

Tags: part-identification

I found about a dozen of these in a mixed bunch of LEGO. Are they actual LEGO pieces or another brand? They are actually white, the pink color is a lighting error.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJlrv.jpg]

Answer (score 3):

This is part 42446 or 28974; [Minifigure, Neck Bracket with Back Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=11304#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).

[image]